# Inner Join on non-key columns in Nhibernate

Tags: sql, fluent-nhibernate

The query I am trying to create in Nhibernate:

```
SELECT _Eligible_Claims.ClaimID, _Eligible_Claims.DateFilled, _Eligible_Claims.NDC, _Eligible_Claims.Cost
From _Eligible_Claims
INNER JOIN _Files_Claims ON _Files_Claims.FileID = _Eligible_Claims.FileID
```

_Eligible_Claims is a view (thus it has no keys) and _Files_Claims has a PK of "FileID."

Eligible_Claims map:

```
public EligibleClaimsMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();
        Table("_Eligible_Claims");

        Id(x => x.UniqueIdentifier, "Id")
            .GeneratedBy.Guid();

        Map(x => x.ApplicationID, "ApplicationID")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.BenOp, "BenOp")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.BenOpID, "BenOpID")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.MemberID, "MemberID")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.ClaimID, "ClaimID")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.NDC, "NDC")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.DateFilled, "DateFilled")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Cost, "Cost")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.DrugID, "DrugId")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.CategoryID, "CategoryId")
            .Nullable();

         Map(x => x.FileID, "FileID")
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
```

_Files_Claims mapping:

```
public ClamFileMap()
    {
        Table("_Files_Claims");

        Id(x => x.ID, "FileID")
            .CustomType<UintToInt>()
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Filename, "FileName")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Size, "FileSize")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.DateCreated, "DateCreated")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.DateEntered, "DateEntered")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.ClientID, "ClientID")
            .Not.Nullable()
            .CustomType<UintToInt>();

        Map(x => x.MasterTable, "MasterTable")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.GUID, "GUID")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Protected, "Protected")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.BatchTimeStamp, "BatchTimeStamp")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.ApplicationID, "ApplicationID")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.ClaimCount, "Claims")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.TotalCost, "ClaimCost")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.PackageID, "PackageID")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.TempDate, "TempDate")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Renamed, "Renamed")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.ERRPPackage, "ERRPPackage")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Removed, "Removed")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.RemovedBy, "RemovedBy")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.RemovedDate, "RemovedDate")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.ImportedBy, "ImportedBy")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.ImportedDate, "ImportedDate")
            .Nullable();

        Map(x => x.ControlTotal, "ControlTotal")
            .Nullable();
    }
```

My current approach:

```
var query = session.CreateCriteria<EligibleClaims>()
                   .CreateAlias("ClaimFile", "claimFile", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
```

I do not expect that to work because will it not attempt to join the PK of EligibleClaims on the FK of ClaimFile by default?  I noticed the "CreateAlias" method has an overload for a 4th parameter of "ICriterion" called "withClause."  Any idea how to implement that?  Or should I be approaching this from another angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also an option is simply mapping a reference to the _Files_Claims table into the EligibleClaims map.  It doesn't HAVE to be a FK but it seems to work anyway:

```
References(x => x.ClaimFile)
            .Column("FileID")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.None();
```

Then use:

```
var query = session.CreateCriteria<EligibleClaims>()
            .CreateAlias("ClaimFile", "claimFile", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

if LINQ is an option

```
var query = from file in session.Query<ClaimFile>()
            from claim in session.Query<EligibleClaims>()
            where file.FileId == claim.FileId
            select new { ... };
```